# I crash whenever I open the first "loading" door

Tags: pc, resident-evil-4-2005

On the PC version of Resident Evil 4, after going past the bridge in the first level where you start off in the house, I crash as soon as I enter the metal door.

Comment: What are your computers specs? Incapability might be the answer.

Comment: Are you playing the original PC version or the [remastered Steam release](http://store.steampowered.com/app/254700/resident_evil_4__biohazard_4/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall the game some files might be missing. If the problem persists lower down your graphical setting. 
You can report the problem on Steam and they will help you.

Comment: "The Steam Beta Patch still won't fix it." Read the question - he's using an update, which doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben, it appears to me that the beta patch **did**, in fact, work.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I reinstalled the game and installed the Beta patch. It might be hit or miss, but it finally worked.

Comment: It appears you have simply commented on the fact that the other users answer worked. Instead, you should mark it as the accepted answer, and perhaps upvote it.